# Why does this recursive function counting nodes in a binary search tree always return a result larger than expected?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The function always returns an answer that is greater than the actual number of nodes by 1 (for example the tree has 3 nodes but it returns 4). I've even tried to excute the code manually on paper and still did not see the problem. Is there any fundamentals about recursion or function that i get wrong here?

```
int countNode (Tree &T)
{
    int count;
    if(T==NULL) return 0; 
    return count++;
    countNode(T->left);
    countNode(T->right);
}
```

This one gives back an answer that is **2**-point greater:

```
int countNode (Tree &T)
{
    int count;
    if(T==NULL) return 0; 
    return count+=1;
    countNode(T->left);
    countNode(T->right);
}
```

This works perfectly, however:

```
int countNode (Tree &T)
{   
    if(T==NULL) return 0; 
    int a = countNode(T->left);
    int b = countNode(T->right);
    int count = a + b + 1;
    return count;
}
```

I understand why the last function works but still don't know what wrong with the first two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the first piece of code you have is closely related to the other issues, so let's focus on it. Here's your code:

```
int countNode (Tree &T)
{
    int count;
    if(T==NULL) return 0; 
    return count++;
    countNode(T->left);
    countNode(T->right);
}
```

There are a few things here to watch out for. First, crank your compiler warning settings up to maximum. You'll likely see several warnings:

1. You never actually initialized the value of `count`, so when you return `count++`, you're returning a garbage value. That likely explains why you're seeing the overcount.
2. If you write `return count++;`, you're saying "increment `count`, then take its old value - which hasn't been incremented - and return it." That's probably not what you wanted to do. If you want increment `count`, just write `count++`. If you want to return `count` + 1, just write `return count + 1;`.
3. The `return` statement you've written will cause your function to exit before making any recursive calls - the calls to `countNode` are never reached and never trigger. You'll probably want to reorder the code or delete the code you've written with the `return` statement in it to address this.
4. You never capture the return value from `countNode`. Remember that each call to `countNode` has its own version of `count`, so simply incrementing `count` in one recursive call won't touch the other versions of `count`. You'll want to store the return values from the two recursive calls, which should return how many nodes are in the left and right subtrees, and figure out how you want to aggregate them together.

I figure compiler warnings would likely flag the first three issues, but that last one is a bit more subtle.

Based on this, can you see what's going on in the other incorrect implementation, and why your last implementation is correct?